# how to assert if else in conditional testing?

Tags: cypress

Hi have this code and i want to assert the $element if visible or not visible. How can i do it? i tried should and expect but its failing

```js
 cy.get('.cloudfront_new_header').then(($element) => {
   if ($element.style.visibility = "hidden"){
     cy.log('Visible')
   } else { 
     cy.log('NotVisible')
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Jquery method `is(':visible')` for this.

```js
cy.get('.cloudfront_new_header').then(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.is(':visible')) {
    cy.log('Visible')
  } else {
    cy.log('NotVisible')
  }
})
```